# Excluding specific text from \justify

Tags: spacing, xetex, lists, text, justification

I have the following LaTeX:

```
\bp This is the first bullet point, the content is long and it spills onto the second line.
\bp This is the second bullet point.
\bp This is the third bullet point. It has a lot of content and takes up three whole lines, making it the longest bullet point out of the three here.
```

With *\bp* defined as so:

```
\newcommand{\bp} {
    \hspace{1mm} \textbullet \hspace{1mm}
}
```

This results in this output...

[image]

---

Adding *\justify* above the text results in this output...
[image]

How can I prevent the bullet point (and associated spacing) being included in the justification, so that they still line up when the text is justified? I would like all the text to be justified, but working around the bullet point part, not with it.

I am using XeLaTeX and I am new to all this, so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Why don't you use a real itemize list?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). As Ulrike says using a real list should just work by defaultt: `\begin{itemize}
\item This is the first bullet point, the content is long and it spills onto the second line.
\item This is the second bullet point.
\item This is the third bullet point. It has a lot of content and takes up three whole lines, making it the longest bullet point out of the three here.
\end{itemize}`. I would recommend also `\usepackage{enumitem}`.

Comment: Where is the `\justify` command defined? The `ragged2e` package defines the `justify` environment, but using `\justify` is wrong to begin with. Please, make a minimal but compilable example producing the output. I'm not able to reproduce it.

Comment: For your happiness, if you are new,  be careful of do not try to reinvent the wheel !  Take your time to learn frst the basic LaTeX syntax. Probably at this point, beside of reading this or that guide for beginners, you should consider use LyX. This WYSIWYM program force you to not write  yourself the code, but obtain a very decent LaTeX output. This way you will learn quickly how  LyX make  common things as list, tables, sections, etc. Then you will be prepared to stay with LyX or pass to a true LaTeX (plain text) editor to go further.